# SQL server query lines output

Tags: sql-server

When I execute the following sql query:

```
select nodename, message from messages, where messages like '%hit%'
```

I get the following output: (string field):

```
oracle01 file system /apl/oracleasm hit 93% usage
         file system /apl/oraclears hit 96% usage
         file system /apl/oracleadv hit 97% usage
```

Is there any way to change my query to get output below  ?

```
oracle01 file system /apl/oracleasm hit 93% usage
oracle01 file system /apl/oraclears hit 96% usage
oracle01 file system /apl/oracleadv hit 97% usage
```

Comment: Possibly.  We will need more information to say for sure.

Comment: @AbeMiessler Yeah, I think that I misunderstood the question and those are the results from his query, not an error message

Comment: Do you care sharing your specific query? Based on the details provided no one will be able to help you.

Comment: I´m using sql server. This script will monitoring file systems usage. That´s not an error message: select nodename, message from messages, where messages like '%hit%'

Comment: I believe the message column contains multi-line data. So the original output shown in your question is actually a single row rather than 3 rows.

Comment: ARS, you´re right. That message  is a string with multi-line data. So, is there any way to format  that output like I need ?

Comment: @ARS, this query is incomplete as the comma after "messages" clearly indicate.

Comment: @user1658549 could you please provide us the complete query adn explain us how you know the 3 lines are related to oracle01 (if it is a constant, then just don't retrieve the column).

Comment: Hi Masters,Follow below complete sql query that I´m using:

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @messages TABLE
(
      nodename VARCHAR(50)
    , [message] VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @messages (nodename, [message])
VALUES 
('oracle01', 'file system /apl/oracleasm hit 93% usage'),
('',         'file system /apl/oraclears hit 96% usage'),
('',         'file system /apl/oracleadv hit 97% usage'),
('oracle02', 'file system /apl/oracleadv hit 99% usage'),
('',         'file system /apl/oracleadv hit 80% usage')

;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
          m.nodename
        , m.[message]
        , RowID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
    FROM @messages m
    WHERE m.[message] LIKE '%hit%' 
)
SELECT
      nodename = 
        CASE WHEN ISNULL(m.nodename, '') = '' 
            THEN (
                SELECT TOP 1 m2.nodename 
                FROM cte m2
                WHERE m2.RowID - 1 < m.RowID
                    AND ISNULL(m2.nodename, '') != ''
                ORDER BY m2.RowID DESC
            ) 
            ELSE m.nodename 
        END
    , [message]
FROM cte m
```

**Output:**

```
nodename    message
----------- ------------------------------------------
oracle01    file system /apl/oracleasm hit 93% usage
oracle01    file system /apl/oraclears hit 96% usage
oracle01    file system /apl/oracleadv hit 97% usage
oracle02    file system /apl/oracleadv hit 99% usage
oracle02    file system /apl/oracleadv hit 80% usage
```

**Update:**

```
DECLARE @messages TABLE
(
      nodename VARCHAR(50)
    , [message] VARCHAR(500)
)

INSERT INTO @messages (nodename, [message])
SELECT 'oracle01', 
'file system /apl/oracleasm hit 93% usage
file system /apl/oraclears hit 96% usage
file system /apl/oracleadv hit 97% usage'

SELECT nodename + ' ' + REPLACE([message], CHAR(10), nodename + ' ')
FROM @messages
```

**Output for update:**

```
oracle01 file system /apl/oracleasm hit 93% usage
oracle01 file system /apl/oraclears hit 96% usage
oracle01 file system /apl/oracleadv hit 97% usage
```

**Update for comment:**

```
SELECT errormessage = 

    n.caption + ' ' + 
    n.ambiente + ' ' + 
    REPLACE(ccs.errormessage, CHAR(10), n.caption + ' ' + n.ambiente + ' ')

FROM dbo.APM_CurrentComponentStatus ccs WITH (NOLOCK) 
JOIN dbo.APM_Application a WITH (NOLOCK) ON ccs.ApplicationID = a.ID 
JOIN dbo.Nodes n WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.NodeID = n.NodeID 
WHERE ccs.ErrorMessage LIKE '%hit%' 
    AND n.ambiente IN ('homologação', 'desenvolvimento')
```

**Is there any way to sort output by MB available ascending ?**

```
DECLARE @table TABLE 
(
      nodename VARCHAR(50)
    , [message] VARCHAR(500)
)

INSERT INTO @table (nodename, [message])
SELECT 'oracle01', 
'FS /bd1/devsdata/logs1 hit 93% usage -> 742 MB available 
FS /bd1/devsdata/logs1 hit 98% usage -> 542 MB available 
FS /bd1/devsdata/tmp hit 99% usage -> 793 MB available'

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
          d.nodename
        , [message] = p.value('(.)[1]', 'VARCHAR(500)')
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              t.nodename
            , kxml = CAST('<r><s>' + REPLACE(t.[message], CHAR(10), '</s>' + '<s>') + '</s></r>' AS XML)  
        FROM @table t
    ) d
    CROSS APPLY kxml.nodes('/r/s') t(p)
) d
ORDER BY d.nodename, SUBSTRING([message], CHARINDEX('-> ', [message]) + 3, CHARINDEX('MB', [message]) - CHARINDEX('-> ', [message]) - 3)
```

**Output:**

```
nodename    message
----------- ---------------------------------------------------------
oracle01    FS /bd1/devsdata/logs1 hit 98% usage -> 542 MB available 
oracle01    FS /bd1/devsdata/logs1 hit 93% usage -> 742 MB available 
oracle01    FS /bd1/devsdata/tmp hit 99% usage -> 793 MB available
```

Comment: You sample code assume that nodetext is empty for some message. However that's not the case. Message Column can have multi-line data. I did update the question to include this information but somehow it was rejected by someone. Please check the comment list in the question which states this.

Comment: Hi Masters, Follow query that I´m using: Select n.caption as server, n.ambiente as environment,ccs.errormessage FROM APM_CurrentComponentStatus ccs WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN APM_Application a WITH (NOLOCK) ON ccs.ApplicationID = a.ID
INNER JOIN Nodes n WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.NodeID = n.NodeID
where ccs.ErrorMessage LIKE '%hit%'  and (n.ambiente='homologação' or n.ambiente='desenvolvimento')
server     environment     errormessage 
server01   Development     FS /bd1/devsdata/logs1 hit 93% usage -> 742 MB available
                           FS /bd1/devsdata/tmp hit 99% usage -> 793 MB available

Comment: Thanks so much for your job ! Is there any way to change this query 
to show me data like a table ouput ?

    Server       FS                     %used   MB Available
    server01    /bd1/teindata/logs1       93      742

Comment: SSMS do not correct supported line breaks in results window. As alternatively can try our product in which implemented this feature - http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/

Comment: Is there any way to sort output by MB available ascending ?

Comment: Your last sql isn´t considering ccs.ErrorMessage ?

Comment: Why do you think that? [message] = ccs.ErrorMessage

Comment: Can you explain me where this select will got data from my DB ? Where is errormessage clausule ?

Comment: No more hints about this ?

Comment: I have no access to your DB. In this case I may only guess how to correctly write the query. And I believe the answer that I gave earlier is quite clear.

Comment: Please try the last query in SSMS.

Comment: Last sql will create a table in my DB ?

Comment: No. It's just a table variable for this example.

Comment: Runnig last query in my Db I only get "querying database..."